# Google Calendar API no description present

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to access my Google Calendar on my linux web server using the PHP API. I connect with the calendar and can see a ton of stuff on those event objects but the description in always empty and there is no where field. These first two work for every event:

```
$event->getSummary();  // gets the correct summary
$event->getStart();    // gets the correct start date
```

These lines returns nothing for every event:

```
$event->getLocation(); 
$event->getDescription();
```

There are no errors or warnings in the log file.

Where do I turn?

[image: Sample Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).  I think you might want to try **getLocation()**

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Event.html) getDescription() should work.

Comment: getLocation() returns nothing. 

I am calling those API functions and there is no server fault or error they just don't return anything. 

$event->getSummary does work. I can list all of my events in the calendar and the date and summary ar correct.

I've run get_class_methods($event); and all of the methods in the API are listed correctly.